# Jquery - if input not empty, add class

Tags: jquery

Heei. I have a question. I want to create if value of input is empty, the label remove class, else (if input has a value)

HTML

```
  <div class="input-field">
            <input type="email" id="username" name="email" required>
            <label for="username">Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      if ($(".input-field:first-of-type input").val() == '') {
        $(".input-field:first-of-type label").removeClass("active");
      }
      else {
        $(".input-field:first-of-type label").addClass("active");
      }
});
```

CSS

```
label.active {
  color: red;
}
```

I hope, the `label` inside `<div class="input-field">` first-of-type will be red when it has a class `active`. But it doesn't work. Any idea please?

My work : https://jsfiddle.net/f7nd0obb/8/

Comment: Hello there i just update your code on jsfiddle and now its working as per your requirement. hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.input-field input').on('keyup', function()
{
    var self = $( this ),
    label = self.siblings('label');

    if ( self.val() != '' ) {
        label.addClass('active');
    } else {
        label.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Might wanna check that logic... why check if it already has the active class?

Comment: Ohh! I think jQuery is already doing that out of the box by checking if a class exists before adding it, but if not, checking for the class is good because you don't want to have the 'active' class more than once on a single element.

Comment: No, my point being that if you were to run your code, every time you clear the input it would toggle the active class.  ie in some cases it would be active and some cases it wouldn't.   You'll also see that "active" means "has a value" (ie is active) so the test would be `self.val()!=''`.  If you change it to that then active would toggle every time you pressed a key as the check if it's already there is *with* the check to see if it should be there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I grasp what you pointed out. I looked at your code and saw the condition you used, so I have updated the code

Comment: Woow, I love it @JohnZenith . It simple for me. Thank your, really thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: So, you copied my answer?  Then got it accepted?  Kudos.

Comment: Glad I could help ☺

Comment: Copied? No, I didn't.

Comment: Ohh! When I said, "I looked at your code" I meant, I looked at the code by 
Bariq Dharmawan who posted the question. That I didn't take notice of.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.input-field input').keyup(function(){
  
  if($(this).val()){
    $(this).parent().find('label').addClass("active");
  }else{
    $(this).parent().find('label').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
label.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" id="username" name="email" required>
  <label  for="username">Email Address</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put your condition in a `change` event handler :

```js
$('#username').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).next().removeClass("active");
  }else{
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
label.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" id="username" name="email" required>
  <label for="username">Email Address</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only runs when *once* - on doc ready.

As neither of your inputs have a value *at that time*, it removes `.active` from both. If you give one your inputs a value at the start, it runs fine:

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7nd0obb/10/

---

It's possible you meant to make this check after the user has had a chance to input some values, so use `input` to update as the user changes the values, eg:

```js
function updateActive() {
  if ($(".input-field:first-of-type input").val() == '') {
    $(".input-field:first-of-type label").removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".input-field:first-of-type label").addClass("active");
  }
}

$(".input-field>input").on("input", updateActive);

// Also on startup
updateActive();
```

```css
label.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" id="username" name="email" required>
  <label for="username">Email Address</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Love it, surely. I appreciate your answer!